# Accessing properties in dropdown list data source for Kendo dropdown list

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have an MVC 5 application that uses a Kendo dropdown list. It uses a list of selector objects, which is a list of these:

```
public class Selector
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public string StartTime { get; set; }
  public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

The dropdown list code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .Name("selectorsDDL")
  .DataTextField("Value")
  .DataValueField("Id")
  .DataSource(source =>
  {
    source.Read(read =>
    {
      read.Action("GetSelectors", "Activation");
    });
   })
   .SelectedIndex(4)
   .Events(ev => ev.Change("onActivationSelectorsChange"))
)
```

Everything works fine, but the problem I'm having is how do I access *StartTime* and *EndTime* for the selected index from the JavaScript *onActivationSelectorsChange* event handler? I can get to the value and text fields ok, but I need to access the other two fields. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for you.

http://dojo.telerik.com/iceDO

Essentially I am using Telerik's demo but here is the change function

```
  function (e) {
      console.log(e);
      var item = this.dataItem(this.selectedIndex);
      $("#object").html(JSON.stringify(item));
  }
```

all I am doing is getting the selected **dataItem** from the change event and based on it's index it will expose all the properties for you.

I have add the additional bit of code so show that selected object is displaying it's properties correctly. So all you would then need to do is modify the code to get the selected property e.g. `item.StartTime`

any issues of further info on this then let me know.

Comment: @SteveGreene How? I asked this almost three years ago and don't see an "accept as answer" box.

Comment: @SteveGreene I'm not an idiot. There is no check mark box.

Comment: @MichaelDay Nobody called you an idiot. I figured with your 1 rating you may not know how to. It probably does have a limit. IAC, the answer helped me, so thanks.